# Bellman-like integral inequality

Tags: integral-inequality, optimal-control, functional-inequalities

I have a weakly decreasing, continuous function $w(\cdot)\geq 0$ on $[0,T]$, with $w(0)=1$. I also have a continuous, decreasing function $b(\cdot)$, where $b(t)\geq 0$ for $t\in[0,T]$. I know that
\begin{align*}
w(t)\leq 1-\int_0^tw(s)b(s)ds
\end{align*}
for all $t\in[0,T]$. I am trying to determine the maximum possible value $w(T)$ under these conditions. Does anyone have suggestions besides trying to formulate this as a control problem? Are there functional/integral inequalities that could work? The ones I have seen all assume that the integral enters with a positive sign on the right hand side.

Comment: With weakly decreasing, continuous function you mean that $d/dt\,w(t)\leq0$ and that $|d/dt\,w(t)|$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: Do you mean that $b$ is fixed and that you look for an optimal $w(T)$ in terms of $b?$

Comment: Yes, $b(\cdot)$ is a known function.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal value of $w(T)$ is
$$
w^* = \left(1+ \int_0^T b(t) \mathrm{d} t\right)^{-1}.
$$

**Upper bound.**
Since $w$ is non-increasing, $\int_0^T w b \geq w(T) \int_0^T b$.
Thus, your constraint applied at the final time is $w(T) \leq 1- w(T) \int_0^T b$, which yields $w(T) \leq w^*$.

**Lower bound.**
Obviously, as soon as $b \neq 0$, this optimal value is not achieved by any continuous $w$ because such a $w$ would satisfy both your initial condition $w(0) = 1$ and the condition $w(t) \equiv w^* < 1$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ to achieve the equality $\int_0^T w b = w^* \int_0^T b$ in the upper bound above.

Nevertheless, you can construct a sequence of functions for which $w(T) \to w^*$, for example by taking $w_n$ defined as follows: $w_n(t) = w^* - \frac{1}{n}$ for $t \geq t_n$ and $w_n$ decreasing linearly from $1$ to $w_n(t_n)$ on $[0,t_n]$, where $0 < t_n \ll 1$ is small enough so that the constraint is satisfied.